# I can't uninstall tuxcut 5.0 (tried everything from purge , autoremove , remove )

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, uninstall

```
lelouch@lelouch-UX360CA:~$ sudo apt-get purge tuxcut 

[sudo] password for lelouch: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tuxcut*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,576 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]  
(Reading database ... 180433 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tuxcut (5.0) ...
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/run-tuxcut': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package tuxcut (--remove):
 installed tuxcut package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tuxcut
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried almost every command i could find to uninstall tuxcut 5.0 and every time I get error (1).

Does anybody know a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I restarted my PC then I used your command:

```
sudo apt-get purge tuxcut
```

and it works fine.